# DataTable with server side - sort/search modified results

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables, server-side

I have a DataTable with the following structure:

```
 $('#table_1').DataTable( 
    {
        "order": [[ 3, "asc" ]],
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "response/cases_main_server_side_processing.php",
        columns: [
                  {
                      data: null,
                      className: "center",
                      defaultContent: '' ,
                       "orderable": false
                  },
                  { data: "ID" },
                  { data: "Status" },
                  { data: "Sale Date" },
                  { data: "Max Bid" },
                  { data: "Zestimate" },
                  {
                      data: null,
                      className: "center",
                      defaultContent: 'Delta',
                      "orderable": false
                  }
              ],

              "createdRow": function( row, data, dataIndex ) 
              {
                    if(data["Max Bid"] == "-100")
                    {
                        row.cells[4].innerHTML = "HIDDEN";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        row.cells[4].innerHTML = Number(data["Max Bid"]/100).toFixed(2).replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$&,');
                    }
       }
} );
```

and here it is the results formatting from cases_main_server_side_processing.php:

```
$columns = array(
    array( 'db' => 'id', 'dt' => "ID" ),
    array( 'db' => 'status',  'dt' => "Status" ),
    array( 'db' => 'ts_sale_date',   'dt' => "Sale Date" ,
            'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) 
            {
                return date( 'm/d/y', strtotime($d));
            }),
    array( 'db' => 'max_bid',  'dt' => "Max Bid"),
    array( 'db' => 'zestimate',  'dt' => "Zestimate" ,
            'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) 
            {
                return number_format((float)($d/100), 2);
            })
);
```

My issues are:

1. I cannot sort or search the column MaxBid (because I process the results back in javascript on "createdRow" function, and it actually sorts/searches directly in the datatbase). How do I do this?
2. What is the proper way to process a cell's value to be searchable/sortable, for example I have to output some cells as currency: $123,456.78 but have them saved as bigints into db: 12345678 ?

scripts I used: [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html)

Comment: The searching & sorting should be done in the server-side code, the parameters are all sent in the ajax call querystring (have a look in the Net panel of Firebug or similar)

Comment: True @markpsmith. Check the post parameters sent via ajax and you can see all columns and if it's orderable or searchable (both regex or not), what columns are sorted and what dir (asc or desc), your current draw number , your search values, length or number of records , start, etc.

Comment: So the only way to do this is to modify the ssp.class.php? (this class is called before outputting the response as json)